# Unable to place an engagement split into a journey after a join activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm trying to add an engagement split into a journey, but it won't let me.

It starts with a random split (10%, 10% then 80%), sends an email, waits and then the three random splits join back together. I'd then like to add the engagement split after the join, but I get the error shown below.

I don't want to add the engagement split before the join as we have 5 streams and 5 waves of emails, it'll become so complicated!

Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding a wait activity after the three random splits join back together? Then you should be able to add the engagement split after the 'wait'.

Comment: I did try that thanks. I've managed to get the split in now, but I had to delete the join out, add the engagement split and then add the join back in. Seems it didn't even like a wait after the join and then the engagement split.

Comment: I guess this is some sort of frontend validation to ensure that there's a wait before the engagement split.